# JQuery Ajax - PostBack issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

[image] In My webApplication, i have load more than 2 userControls (.ascx) using Jquery Ajax. after loading the controls when postback happen on any button event i Receive this error.

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'onsubmit': object is null or undefined"
Please suggest some ideas!

Comment: if your server side code i.e. webmethod is kept on a userControl, you cannot call it. it has to be somewhere else but not a usercontrol .cs page

Comment: can u show ur aspx code..

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use web handlers instead of ajax user control, most of events in the page you can make it using web handlers to Dispense the cost of post back [see here tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)

Comment: Hi Raed Alsaleh, i try loading user controls using web handlers! Any way control gets rendered using this.. HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, false);  Any way clientId for that page(form tag) will be same for all the Usercontrols right!

Comment: where is the problem.. can you explain it agian